# Custom Material UI theme not picked up in emotion component

Tags: material-ui, emotion, themeprovider

Im implementing a mui theme through `createStyles` via `

```js
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
```

which looks something like

```js
createTheme({
 ...other stuff
 borders: { ... }
})
```

The theme gets created fine, and when using `useTheme` in a child component im able to see the custom borders object. However when logging the same from within the styled emotion component, it removes the non standard keys:

```js
  const t = useTheme()
  console.log('t===',t)
  
  const S = styled('div')`
  backgroud-color: ${props => {
    console.log('inside----', props.theme)
    return 'red'
  }}`
```

t=== logs fine with the borders
inside---- logs with the theme but without borders attached

Ive tried importing styled from `@mui/material` instead of `@emotion/styled` and both do the same.
Ive also created a `theme.d.ts` for defining the custom theme via module augmentation but that also doesnt assis

```js
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface CustomTheme {
    borders?: {
      lrg: any;
    };
  }

  interface Theme extends CustomTheme {}
  interface ThemeOptions extends CustomTheme {}
}
```

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: did you try to isolate your problem in something like codesandbox?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?